# Deploy automático com Jenkins/Tomcat7 - Failed to deploy application at context path

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins

Estou tentando configurar o deploy automatico no Jenkins para um servidor Tomcat7. Consegui fazer o Jenkins conectar no manager do Tomcat normalmente, porém por algum motivo quase no fim do processo de deploy ele solta o stack abaixo.

Alguém tem ideia de como corrigir?

> > BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 3 minutes 12 seconds Archiving artifacts Deploying
> >     /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/UNIVERSAL_DS_ODONTO_PR/dist/universal.war
> >     to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
> >     [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/UNIVERSAL_DS_ODONTO_PR/dist/universal.war]
> >     is not deployed. Doing a fresh deployment.   Deploying
> >     [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/UNIVERSAL_DS_ODONTO_PR/dist/universal.war]
> >     ERROR: Build step failed with exception
> >     org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy
> >     [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/UNIVERSAL_DS_ODONTO_PR/dist/universal.war]
> >       at
> >     org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:107)
> >       at
> >     org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:185)
> >       at
> >     hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
> >       at
> >     hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
> >       at
> >     hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
> >       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1018)  at
> >     hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:996)    at
> >     hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
> >       at
> >     hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
> >       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
> >       at
> >     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
> >       at
> >     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
> >       at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)  at
> >     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
> >       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)  at
> >     hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
> >     hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
> >       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404) Caused by:
> >     org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException:
> >     FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /universal
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:566)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:611)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:291)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:102)
>     ... 17 more
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException:
>   FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /universal
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:566)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:611)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:291)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:102)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:185)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
>     at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1018)  at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:996)    at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404) Build step 'Deploy
>   war/ear to a container' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

Context.xml

```
<Context path="/universal"   reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/infodata" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="xxx" password="xxx"
              driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
              url="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=xxxx" />
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução. Esse stacktrace apenas indica de forma genérica que a aplicação não subiu no Tomcat, para encontrar o erro que ocasionou a falha no deploy basta olhar o log da aplicação no Tomcat.

No meu caso em especifico o problema era que o servidor de aplicação estava com a OpenJDK 6 e minha aplicação usa componentes do Java 7, assim gerava o erro `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` no log do Tomcat. Porém poderia ter sido qualquer outro erro que iria ocasionar na mesma mensagem no Jenkins.